# Maven to Eclipse build issue while creating web application

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, cxf

I'm trying to build web Service using maven and eclipse. Here is steps I followed.

1. Generated mvn folder struture using comman prompt
    mvn archetype:generate -    DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-webapp
2. Converted the mvn project into eclipse.

   mvn eclipse:eclipse -Dwtpversion=2.0
3. Imported the project into my workspace.
4. Changed the project facets such as java version, servlet version, added cxf and jaxb feature and server runtime.
5. Copied the WSDL to Resources folder.
6. Since I do not want to add dependencies(as somebody else would be doing this job for me). I added spring and CXF lib into build path. and also to deployment assembly.
7. Generated the jaxb classes and operations from wsdl. Here all the java classes created instead of going to src/main/java to went to src/main/resources.
8. I run the app on tomcat. web.xml is invoked from that cxf framework got invoked and also spring bean creation got invoked. but while creating the bean for the webservice class it threw Class not found error.
9. When I opened up the war I could notice that while packaging instead of placeing the class files, the eclipse placed java file as it is in the war file.

Could some one help me in fixing this problem. Not sure how to configure eclipse to compile and place .class files in the war instead of .java filee.

Comment: Provide your pom.xml. It sounds like a simple configuration problem : generated classes should be found in /target and not in /resources.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out the problem,  while importing the file eclipse is adding command, exclude all the java files from src/main/resources in srource tab of java build path On removing it worked fine